# What is the difference between "rb+" and "ab" in fopen()?

Tags: c, fopen

I do not understand the difference between the `"ab"` and `"rb+"` modes when using `fopen()` in C.

Why would I choose one instead of the other?

Comment: In `a` modes you cannot seek or read; and all writes append to the end of the file.  In `r+` mode you can seek, read, and write.

Comment: .. as is explicitly described in [man 3 fopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html).

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-file-input-output

Comment: [Read what the Standard has to say about this.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p3)

Comment: You literally have to just look at the documentation. Is it *that* difficult?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> With the mode specifiers above the file is open as a text file. In
>   order to open a file as a binary file, a `"b"` character has to be
>   included in the mode string. This additional `"b"` character can either
>   be appended at the end of the string (thus making the following
>   compound modes: `"rb"`, `"wb"`, `"ab"`, `"r+b`", `"w+b"`, `"a+b"`) or be inserted
>   between the letter and the `"+"` sign for the mixed modes (`"rb+"`, `"wb+"`,
>   `"ab+"`).

From [`fopen` documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) which I advise you read before asking questions. It will give you a lot of information about possible parameters, return values, similar functions etc.

Also, from the same document :

> `"a"` = **append**: Open file for output at the end of a file. Output operations always write data at the end of the file, expanding it. Repositioning operations (`fseek`, `fsetpos`, `rewind`) are ignored. The file is created if it does not exist.
>
> `"r+"` = **read/update**: Open a file for update (both for input and output). The file must exist.